# Move multiple txt file based on Prefix Name from Source to Prefix Folder and do alter and move to Target

Tags: python

I want to move multiple txt files from source to target and in between want to do alter into a single file then move to target folder.

My Source Folder Look:  (path\source)

```
1234_01.txt  
1234_02.txt  
9876_01.txt  
9876_02.txt
```

Alter Folder Look:  (path\Alter)

```
1234 (Folder)  (path\Alter\1234)  
1234_01.txt  (files inside the 1234 folder)  
1234_02.txt  (files inside the 1234 folder)   
Output Alter File (Folder inside the 1234 folder)  (path\Alter\1234\Output Alter File)  
1234.txt (Altered File of 1234_01 & 02 inside the Output Alter File)    

9876 (Folder)  (path\Alter\9876)  
9876_01.txt  (files inside the 9876 folder)  
9876_02.txt  (files inside the 9876 folder)   
Output Alter File (Folder inside the 9876 folder)  (path\Alter\9876\Output Alter File)  
9876.txt (Altered File of 9876_01 & 02 inside the Output Alter File)
```

Target Folder

```
1234.txt  
9876.txt
```

Comment: You mean you want to concatenate files with a common prefix?

Comment: @JanWilamowski Yes, combine data from multiple to single txt file based on first prefix name.

Comment: is the intermediate folder `Alter` necessary? And do you have to use Python? This task may be simpler in a shell script.

Comment: @JanWilamowski Yes need intermediate folder Alter (because i received serials files time by time in source) and need to use python.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the file prefix is the part before the underscore.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

source = Path('source')
alter = Path('alter')
alter.mkdir()
for source_file in sorted(source.glob('*.txt')):
    prefix = source_file.name.split('_')[0]
    shutil.copy(source_file, alter)
    combined = alter / prefix / f'{prefix}.txt'
    (alter / prefix).mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    with open(combined, 'at') as handle:
        handle.write(source_file.read_text())

target = Path('target')
target.mkdir()
for target_file in alter.glob('*/*.txt'):
    shutil.copy(target_file, target)
```

I somewhat simplified the folder names but that's easy to modify if needed.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please consider accepting and/or upvoting the answer if it solved your problem.